# How do I resolve the lifetime issues in this code?

Tags: rust, lifetime

```
pub struct Map<'a, F, I, O>
    where F: Fn(I) -> O {
    parser: &'a Parser<'a>,
    mapper: F,
    phantomDataI: PhantomData<I>,
    phantomDataO: PhantomData<O>
}

impl<'a, F, I, O> Map<'a, F, I, O> 
    where F: Fn(I) -> O {
    fn new(parser: &'a Parser, mapper: F) -> Map<'a, F, I, O> {
        Map { parser, mapper, phantomDataI: PhantomData, phantomDataO: PhantomData }
    }        
}
```

When I compile this I get an error...

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
    --> src\combinator\mod.rs:123:9
    |
123 |         Map { parser, mapper, phantomDataI: PhantomData, phantomDataO: PhantomData }
    |         ^^^
    |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 120:1...
--> src\combinator\mod.rs:120:1
    |
120 | / impl<'a, F, I, O> Map<'a, F, I, O>
121 | |     where F: Fn(I) -> O {
122 | |     fn new(parser: &'a Parser, mapper: F) -> Map<'a, F, I, O> {
123 | |         Map { parser, mapper, phantomDataI: PhantomData, phantomDataO: PhantomData }
124 | |     }
125 | | }
    | |_^
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected combinator::Map<'a, _, _, _>, found combinator::Map<'_, _, _, _>)
--> src\combinator\mod.rs:123:9
    |
123 |         Map { parser, mapper, phantomDataI: PhantomData, phantomDataO: PhantomData }
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 122:5...
--> src\combinator\mod.rs:122:5
    |
122 | /     fn new(parser: &'a Parser, mapper: F) -> Map<'a, F, I, O> {
123 | |         Map { parser, mapper, phantomDataI: PhantomData, phantomDataO: PhantomData }
124 | |     }
    | |_____^
note: ...so that types are compatible (expected combinator::Parser<'_>, found combinator::Parser<'_>)
--> src\combinator\mod.rs:123:15
    |
123 |         Map { parser, mapper, phantomDataI: PhantomData, phantomDataO: PhantomData }
    |               ^^^^^^
```

I don't understand why this line is occuring

```
expression is assignable (expected combinator::Map<'a, _, _, _>, found combinator::Map<'_, _, _, _>)
```

Do I need to change my lifetime specifiers somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Parser` in the signature of `new` needs the `'a` lifetime parameter:

```
fn new(parser: &'a Parser<'a>, mapper: F) -> Map<'a, F, I, O>
```

Comment: oh wow, how did I miss that. Every single other set of functions is correct. Thanks very much.